# Does Anyone use Google Cloud Platform for personal use?

Tags: sdk, cloud

This seems like a big business solution to me.  The prices look very expensive.  I have tried to search for this answer but there is no direct answer because I am so far behind in this department obviously.  Can someone chime in please, your help right now would go a long way for me.  Thank you